# why settings not save after close open application , using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

hi this my code to change property from  application setting  (connection string)

i can't use 
my.settings.ConnectionString1= "some connectionstring"
because it read only
so i use 
my.settings.item()= ""

```
 dim x= textbox1.text  ' //  like 127.0.0.1
 My.Settings.Item("ConnectionString1") = "server=" & x & ";user  id=root;password=root;port=3306;database=db1;charset=utf8;"
 My.Settings.Save()
 msgbox(my.settings.ConnectionString1)   ' here change happen 
 Me.Close()
```

after close and open it the i found the value not change

Comment: Make sure that setting is `User` based in the settings....

Comment: Scop = application   , not user

Comment: And if you change it, what happens?

Comment: Settings with Application scope are read-only via `My.Settings`. You can change them via the configuration system but not all users will necessarily have permission to write to the primary config file. Settings with User scope are stored under the user's personal folder, so are guaranteed to be writeable. It you want to edit Application-scoped settings, check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768) out. You can just ignore the encryption part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i  was solved it by declare new variable in "application setting" to store connection string every time changed, and copy it value to the main connection string variable every time loading form

Answer (score -1):

try to use:

```
My.Settings.ConnectionString1 = "server=" & x & ";user  id=root;password=root;port=3306;database=db1;charset=utf8;"
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: i solved it by declare new variable in " application setting " to store connection string  every time changed , and copy it vale to  the main  connection string variable every time loading form

Comment: ConnectionString 1 declared inside application scope which is not supporting initial by equation